# sync gradle error in Amazon aws's MySampleApp

Tags: android, amazon-web-services

I am new to android app development. I am trying to build an app and I am trying  amazon aws to host. I opened MySampleApp they provided in Android Studio but I am unable to build the project.
I see this error. 
Error:Unknown host 'jcenter.bintray.com'. You may need to adjust the proxy settings in Gradle.
Enable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project
[Learn about configuring HTTP proxies in Gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#sec:accessing_the_web_via_a_proxy)

Comment: Do you have a working internet connection ?

Comment: @JonasCz Yes I do.

Comment: Can you access http://jcenter.bintray.com/ from your desktop? Are your behind some firewall that's blocking it?